# Basic Angular POST Format Explanation

Tags: angularjs, post

I really don't understand what I am doing with angular post. For example:

```
$http.post("http://localhost:999333/api/econdata", $scope.econData)
.success(function (response) { $scope.responseEconData = response; });
}
```

So, I have a post. I am only GUESSING at what I am doing - the angular "$http" object has a method called post that takes some parameters - the link to my POST controller (what url to post to) and "econData," which is the post message. I believe it can be overloaded, but whatever.

However, I don't understand the ".success" format at all. Why is there what looks like another method? Can someone explain this to me or break it down into "simpler" code?

Also, why is the post self-invoking? What do I do if I want to run the post onClick or something?

edit: The code posted is inside a controller and works perfectly. I just don't understand why/how.

Answer (score 2):

Promises are a way of handling asynchronous functions.  The post method returns a promise *before* it actually posts anything, i.e., it returns the promise object immediately. At that point the promise doesn't hold the result of the post, but it does have a success method that you then use to define a function that will be called when the post completes. The argument that will be passed to that function will be the response from the post.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand it, the http post returns a [promise object](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) . Success is calling the success function on the promise object.

Angular docs:
The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns apromise with two $http specific methods: success and error.

Answer (score 1):

$http is asynchronous.  The success method of the $http service call accepts a callback handler, that angularjs will call for you when it eventually succeeds.  The argument passed to your success handler will be the return value from your service call, converted to JSON format.